# What does -f in an if conditional mean in shell script?

Tags: shell

tmpFilename="buildDefTemp.txt"

```
if [ -f $tmpFilename ]; then
    rm -f $tmpFilename
fi
if [ -f $buildDefinitionFile ]; then
    rm -f $buildDefinitionFile
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

```
[ -f FILE ] True if FILE exists and is a regular file.
```